# I want the multiple choice option about the button how to do it?

Tags: user-interface, figma, rapid-prototyping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuTur.png)

As you can see it in figma . please help me out.

i tried to to make in open above the button but it did not. & it opened below the button.
Help me out as i'm not able to find the solution.